# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, mediapipe

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\Sampath\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~5py\defs.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I tried  pip install mediapipe

Comment: Did you try following the error message? You can attach `--user` to install it.

Comment: Try using the anaconda installer `conda install mediapipe`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as we can read in the comments to the answer, restarting the computer solved the problem, so it is clearly not a programming question.

Comment: If opening terminal as admin fails, try closing all the applications which may be using the environment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`EnvironmentError: Access is denied` errors usually stem from one of three reasons:

1. You do not have the proper permissions to install these files, and you should try running the same commands in an Administrator Command Prompt. 90% of the time, this should solve the problem.
2. You don't have permission to install the package system-wide. You can instead install it for only your user by adding the `--user` flag:

```bash
pip install --user <PACKAGE>
```

3. If that doesn't work, then the problem is usually from an external program accessing a file, and you (or the installation script) are trying to delete that file (you cannot delete a file that is opened by another program). Try to restart your computer, so that whatever process is using that file will be shut down. Then, try the command again.

Comment: I restarted my PC, then I solved the problem. Thank You

Comment: @SampathSandaruwan No problem! If my answer helped, be sure to upvote it and click the green checkmark to mark it as valid :)